# Is there a way to retrieve MATLAB busy status from a C# application

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I am developing an application that determines matlab is idle for some time. I do this by calculating cpu times for now. I wonder if there is a way to retrieve matlab busy status (running a script) from my external c# application.

Thanks.

Comment: why `python-idle` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do it from Matlab (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32005-cmdwintool). However, there doesn't exist a documented request that Matlab offers for C#.

Be that as it may, you can just raise a flag in your Matlab code -you can further utilize GUI callbacks or waitbar- when you start your progress. It can be as simple as just writing 0/1 to a text file or basically anything you wish via the system() command. Just clear the flag when your Matlab process finishes and check the flag in your C# application.

Comment: You can use [`oncleanup`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/oncleanup.html) to automatically clear the flag when the function terminates (which would work even if there's an error thrown by the function).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually i need and idle detector for my company users. I run a windows service that determines if specific matlab instance is idle or not by calculating its cpu / memory and IO usage for now. I want to convert this method to retrieve its busy flag by asking matlab instance. Is this possible?

Comment: There doesn't exist a documented feature for that. You could impose your clients to start all of their work with a predefined flag script if you really must. It could be right along with the usual: close all; clc; flagScript(); but other than that I am not sure. You could look at Yair's blog and maybe even ask him about this. He's the man for undocumented Matlab features. Blog link:
https://undocumentedmatlab.com/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I’ll check it.